# Cloudflare Pages build fails: "could not resolve..."

Tags: reactjs, vite, cloudflare

I've recently switched from create-react-app to vite to start my hobby React projects.

**What worked previously with CRA...**

In the past I could easily publish my create-react-app on Cloudflare Pages:

- Connect Cloudflare Pages to my Github repo;
- Choose Framework preset: "Create React App";
- Set build command to: "npm run build";
- Set build output directory to: "build".

And my app would be published.

**... doesn't work with vite**

Unfortunately, I can't get this to work with Vite. I've started a new vite project (npm create vite@latest) and copied my components there. I'm using 2 subfolders in /src, called 'components' and 'pages'.

On my development machine, I can succesfully run "npm run dev", "npm run build" and "npm run preview" for this new Vite powered version of my app. However, I am unable to publish the app to Cloudflare pages.

Each build keeps failing with errors like:

> Could not resolve "./Snackbar" from "src/components/PublicRoutes.jsx"

(and different source/target files).

For the last few days, I've taken a number of troubleshooting steps. With different parameters:

- Connect Cloudflare Pages to my new Vite Github repo;
- Choose Framework preset: "None" (also tried "Vue", "Create React App" and "React Static")
- Set build command to: "npm run build";
- Set build output directory to: "dist (also tried "build").

**I've tried different relative path notations...**

The paths work locally, but I've changed my import statements multiple times to test with Cloudflare Pages:

- import MySnackbar from "Snackbar";
- import MySnackbar from "./Snackbar";
- import MySnackbar from "./../components/Snackbar";

Building keeps failing...

**...and absolute paths**

After this, I've tried using "absolute" paths by adding the following code to vite.config.js:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: "/src",
    },
  },
});
```

And changed all import statements for my modules to "/src/components/[modulename]" or "/src/pages/[pagename]". This changed the Cloudflare build error to:

> [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "/src/components/Snackbar"
> from "/opt/buildhome/repo/src/pages/Login.jsx".

**Why won't Cloudflare Pages build my app?**

Should I add extensions to my imports? What am I doing wrong here?

This has cost me a few days by now, so your help is highly appreciated!

Thank you for your time, please let me know if I should provide more details.

(and sorry for the long post!)

Maarten

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer what is happening but I had this issue and I changed the name of the components dir to something else and the build worked. I then changed it back to components and it was built. Weird, but solved the issue.